# throw err when connecting to mongodb in VM using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vagrant

I'm running my mongodb in virtualbox using vagrant. I'm trying to connect to the database on my host machine using node.js, but I get thrown a strange err when trying to do so. This is the code i'm running.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:6600/test";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
  if (err){
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

This is the error that is shown in command line.

```
C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\testingGrounds>node createMongoDB.js

C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\testingGrounds\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:421
          throw err
          ^
[object Object]
```

And this is a relevant part of the Vagrantfile.

```
  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  # nginx
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 6600
  # # development site
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 6660
  # db browser port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7474, host: 6666
  # test port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8800, host: 6606
```

Comment: There is likely a more specific error you are not showing, or perhaps you should try `console.error(err)` instead in order to see it better if not. But `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 6660` seems to indicate that you are forwarding from port `80` to your local `6600`, and MongoDB runs on port `27017` by default. So unless you specifically assigned it to port `80` ( and you likely did not ) then you are connecting to the wrong port, and even basically have the wrong port forwarding set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vagrant for some dev/test running on local, just use a *static ip* it will simplify your life.

You can remove all the forwarded ports line from your Vagrantfile and replace with:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

In the VM, you need to make sure mongo is bound to this IP or 0.0.0.0 so it can listen to all network interfaces, in the `/etc/mongod.conf` file, make sure to have

```
bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```

or

```
bind_ip=192.168.33.10
```

In your node code, you will need to replace the url for mongo to `mongodb://192.168.33.10:27017/test` (assuming mongo is running on port 27017; if you have made a change in your conf file, align here)